Getting error while querying the json data on Athena
I have JSON data stored in S3, and I want to query it using Athena. I used an AWS Glue crawler to retrieve the metadata and columns, which were fetched correctly, but I'm still unable to query the data.
I am getting this error :
COLUMN_NOT_FOUND: Column 'metadata' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources
This query ran against the "ocsf-database" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id:
I am expecting to fetch the data using query in athena

can you provide us a sample of your json file pls ? thank you

You have to add the query you're trying to run and your table structure from Athena, otherwise it would be so hard to help you.
Usually Athena works with JSON based on the way you configured the crawler to read the data and store it from your S3 files, maybe you stored the data as normal string and you're trying to access one of the attributes or your parsed structure is not what you're actually expecting and for this you have to check the table structure

{
"info": {
"item": {
"revision": "5.67",
"title": "AirQualityMonitor",
"creator": "DataCorp",
"feature": {
"title": "Environmental Monitoring and Analysis"
}
}
this is kind of json structure that i am using, and the query that i am using to fetch the data in the athena is :
SELECT * FROM "database"."table" limit 10;

Would you please add the table structure that you see in Athena? Seems like the crawler has created a schema that's not valid
